# Executing commands incorrectly in Jenkins pipeline shell script

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipenv, pyenv

I set pyenv to an enabled state. And if there is no python version corresponding to the pipfile through pipenv, I tried to install the corresponding python version automatically through pyenv.

> [Reference] Automatically install required Python version when pyenv
> is available. at https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

This attempt works fine when I connect to the server via ssh and run it as an interactive command.

Please refer to the example below. A case of connecting to the server with ssh and using the command

```
<Pipfile>
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8.13"
```

I run pipenv install and get the following message.

```
> pipenv install    
Warning: Python 3.8.13 was not found on your system…
Would you like us to install CPython 3.8.13 with pyenv? [Y/n]: Y
Installing CPython 3.8.13 with pyenv (this may take a few minutes)…
```

However, if Jenkins is installed on the same server and the command is executed with a shell script in the Jenkins pipeline, the server gives different results than with the interactive command.

Please refer to the example below.
This is an example of using a shell script in the jenkins pipeline.

```
# Before starting this pipeline, pyenv version 3.8.13 was uninstalled and the pipenv environment was also removed. 
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh 'pipenv install'
            }
        }
    }
}​
```

When the above pipeline was executed, a message asking whether to install Python 3.8.13 did not appear, and a virtualenv was created using the system Python 3.7 version on the server.

```
Warning: Python 3.8.13 was not found on your system…
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.7.3) to create virtualenv…
```

I don't know why it behaves differently than when I entered an interactive command on the server.

The PATH and ENV of Jenkins and the server are the same, and the pyenv and pipenv commands in the Jenkins pipeline shell script work well.

Same as the server Is there a way to install the 3.8.13 version when the pipenv install command is executed in the Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: pipenv probably detects that the running instance is not associated with interactive terminal and wont ask question anything .. you could try `PIPENV_YES=1 pipenv install` as your sh ..

Comment: thank you for your reply.
but, I've already tried running it. 

And I tried `PIPENV_YES=1 USING_DEFAULT_PYTHON=false pipenv install` 

The result is the same, and version 3.7.3 is installed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your  question is. Are you surprised that subsequent `sh` invocations can't see the effects of this step? That's how it works; each `sh` is executed in a separate process, similarly to if you would `exit` from the interactive session and start a now one.

Comment: @tripleee "Would you like us to install CPython 3.8.13 with pyenv? [Y/n]:" The reason the statement doesn't appear is because the session ends right away and runs in a separate process?

Comment: Probably a different question than I imagined then. Perhaps you could [edit] to clarify this detail?